# Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 51 and input n_features is 55 error with BERT tokenizer

Tags: text-classification, bert-language-model

I am working on classification model. I have a `Description` column in my data on which I am using Bert tokenization.

```
def tokenization_and_encoding(data,model_name,independent_col,target_col):
    
    tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(model_name,do_lower_case=True)
    train_text=list(data[independent_col])
    train_labels=list(data[target_col])
    train_encodings = tokenizer(train_text, truncation=True, padding=True,max_length=256)
    train_encodings=train_encodings['input_ids']
    return train_encodings,train_labels


model_name='uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/'

data=data[['Description','Target']]
    
#drop null values
data = data[data['Outage Description'].notnull()]

calibrated_svc = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(), method='sigmoid')
calibrated_svc.fit(train_encodings,train_labels)

length_of_encoding = len(train_encodings[0])##length is 51

pickle.dump(calibrated_svc, open(r".\model\bert__"+str(length_of_encoding)+".pkl", 'wb'), protocol=4)

#########################################################################
##########################Prediction#####################################


tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(model_name,do_lower_case=True)


#get test text
test_text=list(test_data[independent_col])
#

#set encoding size
test_encodings_fix=[0]*51

#encode text
test_encodings = tokenizer(test_text, truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=256)
test_encodings=test_encodings['input_ids']

#make encoding fix lenght
for enc in test_encodings:    
   test_encodings_fix_trim=test_encodings_fix[len(enc):51]
   enc.extend(test_encodings_fix_trim)

#load model
Pkl_Filename = r'\model_new\bert_model.pkl'
with open(Pkl_Filename, 'rb') as file:
    Pickled_svc_Model = pickle.load(file)

#predict
predict_svc_test_pred_bbc = pd.DataFrame(Pickled_svc_Model.predict(test_encodings))
```

Running the prediction module throwing me error as :

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 51 and input n_features is 55.
```

When I checked the `test_encoding` there the value is 55.

My training data has 105 records and test data has 5 records.

I am not able to figure it out where I need to fix.

Comment: The test data encoding should be the same as the training data encoding, not a new one.

Comment: @Erwan - How to resolve this problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bert so I don't know exactly how to do it but I'm pretty sure it's due to using a different encoding for the test set. In case nobody answers on SO, you could try to ask your question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.